Laplace transforms coinciding on a vertical line
It is a well known result that if two Laplace transforms $L(f_1)$ and $L(f_2)$ coincide for a periodic set of values along an horizontal line, then it follows that $f_1=f_2$ a.e.
I was wondering if I can ascertain the same for vertical lines, and if not a counterexample would be useful.
I don't believe it's necessarily true for vertical lines and here's my intuition since the proof (Doestch book page 23) makes use of the vanishing of the moments on finite intervals $$ \int_{0}^{1} x^n \psi(x) \,dx\ = 0 $$ implying $\psi(x)=0$ which by the way it is constructed implies $f=0$
However, if I emulate the proof for vertical lines I obtain $$ \int_{0}^{1} e^{in \log(x)} \psi(x) \,dx\ = 0 $$ and I cannot use the vanishing of moments.
